# C# StreamWriter - Probable I/O race condition detected while copying memory

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, thread-safety, streamwriter

I have an application that uses a logger.
The same logger can write from various program in the same file.
It is used for long-lasting executions.

Only once I got the following error:
[image]

The referred line is

```
    swLogger.WriteLine(newLines);
```

I have found the same problem referred in various online threads mostly with Console.WriteLine.
I must admit that -besides reading them- I still have not a complete understanding of the problem.

Since it happened only once I could not reproduce the issue.

That being said -if my understanding of the problem is not mistaken - could a solution be put a **lock** instruction encompassing the whole routine?

The code is:

```
public static bool WriteLog(string newLines, bool AddDateTime = true, bool ShowMessageBox = false)
{

    try
    {

        long max = MaxLogSizeMB * 1024 * 1024;

        if (lenTot > max)
        {
            if (swLogger != null)
                swLogger.Close();
            File.Delete(FileName);
            swLogger = new StreamWriter(FileName);
            lenTot = 0;
        }

        if (AddDateTime)
            newLines = "[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss.fff") + "] " + newLines;
            lenTot += newLines.Length + 2;//Environment.Newline
            swLogger.WriteLine(newLines);<-----

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

So the logger flow is opened at the beginning, written all the times and closed at the end.

Thanks in advance for any help

Patrick

Comment: Hi, please consider [log4net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net) or [Serilog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog) framework. They are thread safe by design so you don't need this hassle ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes a shared lock will work, but it will block the caller whilst the lock is being acquired, and for the duration of the lock other threads will block trying to acquire the lock; this could impact performance. You could get round this by have a dedicated thread that writes to the file from a queue of items to be logged, and only add new items to the queue from the calling thread. Once you start getting that complicated, you are much better off using an of-the-shelf logging library like log4net, which will do all this for you.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I think I will go for the log4net solution. That said -just for understanding what solution would be better as an alternative: 1. use to lock for preventing double access to the streamwriter so not getting an exception 2. not to use a lock, put it in a try catch but disregarding the execption ? Which one would be faster? Thanks

Comment: It is impossible to choose between 1 & 2 because there are so many unknown factors which are unique to your situation. You would need to profile both in your target environment to decide between them (if you want to spend the effort doing that rather than using e.g., log4net).

Comment: @Polyfun, I have a situation when we have only a single thread which accesses the StreamWriter object and writes to a filestram (using queue). However, the same I/O race condition was logged on the user's machine. We can't reproduce this error. Are there any other cases when even a single thread can cause this exception?

Comment: @ChuckNorris I suggest you log the thread id of the logging thread that is accessing the StreamWriter each time you write to it. This will prove how many threads are writing to the StreamWriter.